# How to avoid TLE when array is used to store 1 *10^5 integer entries

Tags: c++, arrays

My code is showing TLE when there when number of entries in array(n) is 1 *10^5. What should i do? I saw the submission status and in all cases it ran fine except in the last case when n is 100 000, it shows time limit error.

Problem:: https://codeforces.com/contest/474/problem/B
My solution:  https://pastebin.com/5RLBirpF

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(NULL);
  cout.tie(NULL);
  int t;
  cin>>t;
  int arr[t];
  int arrfreq[t];
  int sum=1;
  for(int i=0;i<t;i++ )
  {
    cin>>arr[t];
    sum+=arr[t];
    arrfreq[i]=sum;     
}

int m;
cin>>m;
int qsn[m];
int k;
for(int i =0;i<m;i++)
{
  cin>>qsn[i];
}

for(int j =0;j<t;j++)
{
    if(k<arrfreq[j])
    {
      cout<<j+1<<"\n";
      break;
    }
    if(k==arrfreq[j])
      {
        cout<<j+2<<"\n";
        break;
      }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you explain more on possible unknown words `TPE` (abbrevation for what) and `1 lakh`? Please also remove unnecessary _empty lines_ in your code.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` - Don't *ever* do that.

Comment: `int arr[t];` is a _variable-length array_, and is not C++.  Some compilers support it, as an extension (borrowing from C99).  And is probably blowing your stack.  Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @hc_dev, TLE stands for "time limit exceeded".

Comment: A rule of thumb is that TLE errors are caused by inefficient algorithms.  Most likely, you'll need a better algorithm.  You may be able to shave off some time by optimizing your implementation, but in general, you'll need a more efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You are using one loop for calculating the number of pile. What you can do instead is find the answer in the same loop in which you are taking the input for qsn. Just take the input of qsn and find the pile number in that loop itself. That will reduce your code's time complexity and remove the TLE error.

Comment: did what u say, still it is showing TLE....Just showing last changed part of the code.Let me know if you meant something else.

int k;
for(int i =0;i<m;i++)
{
  cin>>qsn[i];
  k=qsn[i];

  for(int j =0;j<t;j++)
{
    if(k<arrfreq[j])
    {
      cout<<j+1<<"\n";
      break;
    }
    if(k==arrfreq[j])
      {
        cout<<j+2<<"\n";
        break;
      }
}

}


}

Answer (score 0):

I saw other solutions on the internet and found out that std::lower_bound function is what has to be used to avoid T.L.E.

But one thing, as mentioned on internet, this function returns a pointer to the lower bound, then , why are we subtracting c from it and then +1 also(in the 2nd last cout line)??(refer to the code.)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,i,m,j,cnt=0,ans,x,sum=0;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n],c[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       cin>>a[i];
       sum+=a[i];
       c[i]=sum;
    }
    cin>>m;
    int b[m];
    for(i=0; i<m; i++) cin>>b[i];
    for(j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
         cout<<lower_bound(c,c+n,b[j])-c+1<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```